# pandas dataframe binning and grouping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, binning

I have a data frame with the following content

```
date                    val

2010-01-01 20:46:15.00  7665
2010-01-01 20:46:55.20  2878
2010-01-01 20:47:55.20  8211
2010-02-12 03:08:03.20  0027
2010-02-12 03:09:10.07  3319
2011-04-21 11:46:14.40  3239
2011-04-21 11:47:08.12  7665
2012-06-25 12:42:03.09  7750
2012-06-25 13:38:54.88  7740
```

I want the data to be binned such that I have a new column such that it contains the val which co-appeared during 10 minute duration.  In the above example, it will be like

```
bin                                   vals_in_bin
2010-01-01 00:00:00.00 - 00:10:00.00    None
.
.
2010-01-01 20:40:00.00 - 20:50:00.00   7665,2878,8211
.
.
```

Then I want to find the Top 10 pairs of vals which co-appears in this new data

For example, if we assume that the vals (7665, 2878, 8211) co-appear in the new data most times, this will result in 3 top co-appearing pairs (7665,2878), (7665, 8211), (2878,8211).  I need to get such pairs corresponding to 10 top co-appearing pairs.

So far, what I succeeded is creating bins as per time.  But I do not know how to group val based on this bins

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_loc))
data= data.drop_duplicates()
data.reindex()
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
start_time = data['date'].min()
end_time = data['date'].max()
bins = pd.date_range(start = start_time, end=end_time, freq='10T')
```

Comment: `df.astype(str).groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('10min'))['val'].apply(','.join).resample('10min').first()` ..?

Comment: @ChrisA. do you have any suggestion for doing the second part efficiently ?

Comment: hmmm looks kind of like [apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) might be worth looking into..?

Comment: @ChrisA. you mind to care what exactly that piece of code doing ?  Is there any randomness in it ?  I get different result in each run.